# Matching string elements in Python (apply function)

Tags: python, function, loops, apply, string-matching

I have Twitter data, and I'm attempting to return all states abbreviations that match the user's self-described location. I've created a matching function and applied it to my data frame, but for some reason I'm not returning any matches (all NaNs) in spite of there being state abbreviations in the original data.

My state list includes all 50 states

states = ['AL','AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA'...]

A small sample of my dataframe looks like such:

```
        user_location            text
0   CO                           australia to manufacture covid vaccine and g...
1   Seattle, WA                  coronavirusvaccine coronavaccine covidvaccine ...
2   nan                          deaths due to covid in affected countries re...
3   Atlanta, GA                  subhashree stay safe di amp da
```

I created the following nested loop function to try to return matches of location from my states list with the user_location column:

```
def match(user_location):
    for state in states:
        if state in tweets2.user_location:
            return state
        else:
            return np.nan
```

I then created a new column of the returned matches by applying my function:

```
tweets2['State'] = tweets2['user_location'].apply(match)
```

However, all I'm getting returned are NaN values, when I know there are surely state abbreviations within the user_location column.

I checked using the following code:

```
tweets2['State'].notnull().value_counts()
```

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your else statement is the problem

Comment: @SreeramTP may you point out the exact issue? I want to return NaN if it doesn't match in order to keep the resulting object the same length as my current DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the value always after first iteration of the loop. Try to avoid using return inside the loop. Let's rebuild your loop:

```py
def match(user_location):
    user_state = np.nan
    for state in states:
        if state in user_location:
            user_state = state
            break
    return user_state

print(match(tweets2.user_location))
```

You can do a bit more elegant thing with sets. If you make `states` a set, than you can do following: `states.intersection(tweets2.user_location)` which will return a set of items existing in both sets.

Comment: I tried running this, and I'm still returning a column of all NaN values, oddly...Could it be my .apply clause that is broken? I'll try using sets

Comment: I made a typo and fixed it. If it doesn't work, could you please make `print(tweets2.user_location)` and post an output? Perhaps it contains non string types

Comment: Worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: btw, is it possible that user can have multiple locations? Because now it returns only first matching

Comment: Just one here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are returning nan as soon as one state is not found, like below

```
def match(user_location):
    for state in states:
        if state in tweets2.user_location:
            return state
        else:
            return np.nan
```

You should change it such a way that it return nan only after checking all the states. For that you can code like this,

```
def match(user_location):
    for state in states:
        if state in tweets2.user_location:
            return state
     return np.nan
```

Comment: I'm receiving the following error with that code: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I fixed that, and I'm still getting all NA values. Could the problem be with my apply function? Thanks for the help.